# How does a parent component communicate with a child component that was passed in as a prop?

Tags: reactjs

```
function Parent({children}) {
  // How does Parent pass in state to children
  // And how does Parent get state from children?
  return <div>{children}</div>
}
```

How does Parent pass in state to children?
And how does Parent get state from children?

Answer (score 1):

I've not tested it but the following should work AFAIK. Gist of it is that you can use `React.cloneElement(...)` to inject the props

```
function Parent({children}) {
  const someOtherProp = 'a prop value';
  return <div>{
    React.Children.map(
      children,
      child => React.cloneElement(child, {...child.props, someOtherProp})
    );
  }</div>
}
```

That'll let you pass state down to children. As for passing state back up you can't, however the general approach would be to store the state at this parent level and pass *setter functions* to the children (i.e. when the child calls `setStateValue(...)` it's actually setting parent state).